# Variadic templates for lambda expressions

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++11

What's the correct way to do this with g++:

```
template < typename F >
void g (F f);

template < typename ... A >
void h (A ... a);

template < typename ... A >
void f (A ... a) {
  g ([&a] () { h (a...); }); // g++-4.6: error: parameter packs not expanded with »...«
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to expand the pack `a` in the capture list as well, like this:

```
template < typename ... A >
void f (A ... a) {
  g ([&, a...] () { h (a...); }); 
}
```

Here is the relevant text from the C++0x Final Committee Draft, section 5.1.2.23:

> A capture followed by an ellipsis is a
>   pack expansion (14.5.3). [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class... Args> void f(Args... args) {
>     auto lm = [&, args...] { return g(args...); }; lm();
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: Thank you. g++-4.6 doesn't accept this syntax from the draft yet: test01.cc:2:23: Fehler: expected »,« before »...« token

Comment: I solved it by making a tuple, passing it to the lambda function and unpacking there.

Comment: It looks like g++-4.8 still doesn't accept this syntax, but ICC 13.0.1 does: http://bit.ly/14auYGy

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
template < typename ... A >
void f (A ... a) {
  g (std::bind(h, a...));
}
```