# How to combine std::bind(), variadic templates, and perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I want to invoke a method from another, through a third-party function; but both use variadic templates. For example:

```
void third_party(int n, std::function<void(int)> f)
{
  f(n);
}

struct foo
{
  template <typename... Args>
  void invoke(int n, Args&&... args)
  {
    auto bound = std::bind(&foo::invoke_impl<Args...>, this,
                           std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    third_party(n, bound);
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  void invoke_impl(int, Args&&...)
  {
  }
};

foo f;
f.invoke(1, 2);
```

Problem is, I get a compilation error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1206:35: error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
```

I tried using a lambda, but [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378709/948128) GCC 4.8 does not handle the syntax yet; here is what I tried:

```
auto bound = [this, &args...] (int k) { invoke_impl(k, std::foward<Args>(args)...); };
```

I get the following error:

```
error: expected ‘,’ before ‘...’ token
error: expected identifier before ‘...’ token
error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
note:         ‘args’
```

From what I understand, the compiler wants to instantiate `invoke_impl` with type `int&&`, while I thought that using `&&` in this case would preserve the actual argument type.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks,

Comment: GCC 4.8 handles the syntax perfectly. What did you try?

Comment: @ArneMertz I updated the question with the syntax I tried

Comment: seems you just encountered a bug in gcc, it should work: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41934

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Binding to `&foo::invoke_impl<Args...>` will create a bound function that takes an `Args&&` parameter, meaning an rvalue. The problem is that the parameter passed will be an *lvalue* because the argument is stored as a member function of some internal class.

To fix, utilize reference collapsing rules by changing `&foo::invoke_impl<Args...>` to `&foo::invoke_impl<Args&...>` so the member function will take an lvalue.

```
auto bound = std::bind(&foo::invoke_impl<Args&...>, this,
                       std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

[Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/4DGVCV#view_edit_box).

Comment: Actually, it seems that this solution does not work if I use a `std::reference_wrapper` as argument, here is an example: http://ideone.com/VBxfZd; am I missing something regarding usage of reference wrappers?

Comment: @piwi Then change `Args&...` to `Args const&...`. Not entirely sure why it works though.

Comment: My bad, I could have come up with this ;-) Thanks.