# std::bind with variadic template and auto return type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

Following the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18380820), I have a `std::bind` with a variadic template function. If I try to provide a function template with `auto` return, gcc rejects the program:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename... Args
auto inv_impl(Args... a) { return (a + ...); }

template <typename... Args>
auto inv(Args... args) {
  auto bound = std::bind(&inv_impl<Args...>, args...);
  return bound;
}

int main() {
  auto b = inv(1, 2);
}
```

The compile error is:

```
foo.cc: In instantiation of ‘auto inv(Args ...) [with Args = {int, int}]’:
foo.cc:41:30:   required from here
foo.cc:36:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int&, int& ’
   auto bound = std::bind(&inv_impl<Args...>, args...);
                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from foo.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/functional:808:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)’
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/functional:808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:36:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Func’
   auto bound = std::bind(&inv_impl<Args...>, args...);
                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from foo.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/functional:832:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Result, class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bindres_helper<_Result, _Func, _BoundArgs>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)’  
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/functional:832:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:36:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Result’
   auto bound = std::bind(&inv_impl<Args...>, args...);
                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cc:37:10: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘bound’
   return bound;
          ^~~~~ 
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:41:8: error: ‘void b’ has incomplete type
   auto b = inv<int, int>(1, 2);
        ^
```

As far as I see, return types spelled out by me work, and it's only `auto` return types that the compiler can't handle.

Is there a way I can return from inv_impl without knowing the return type at code-write time?
(I'm playing with `declval`/`decltype` constructs but I'm wondering if there's something better)

Comment: Interesting. It seems to me that your example is overcomplicated: you can obtain the same error (from g++; no error from clang++) with `#include <functional>

template <typename T> auto foo (T) { return 1;}

int main () { 
    auto bound = std::bind(&foo<int>, 1);
}`

Comment: It seems to be a gcc bug, compile as expected with clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f54400d74897012). As workaround, you may use: `template <typename... Args> auto invoke_impl(Args... a) -> decltype((a + ...)) { return ( a + ...); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a gcc bug (filed [86826](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86826)).

The solution is to just... not use `std::bind()`. There's hardly ever a reason to anyway. Lambdas are strictly superior:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto inv(Args... args) {
  return [=]{ return inv_impl(args...); };
}
```

Comment: Btw, it is not `std::bind` which is "problematic" (for the bug), but taking reference of the function.