# deduced return type with function template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
#include<functional>

template<typename T>
T f() { return T{}; }

template<typename T>
auto g() { return T{}; }

int main() { 
    std::function<int()> a = f<int>;  // ok, clang and gcc
    std::function<int()> b = g<int>;  // ok, clang, error gcc
}
```

The error in gcc is

```
error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<int()>' requested
```

Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/LQFbth) to experiment with.

I don't understand why the program compiles only if the return type is `T`, and fails on gcc when the return type is deduced.

Edit: The comments suggest this is a gcc bug, but could I get a confirmation that the program is indeed well formed?

Comment: Seems like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86826 - Which also points at this potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643222/stdbind-with-variadic-template-and-auto-return-type

Comment: Nice. It's not unusual that g++ and clang++ disagree. If they do, we as users won't have an easy time. The [tag:language-lawyer] tag may draw some attention to the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why not? Might as well get a confirmation that the code is sound. As it seems to be.

Comment: fwiw, you can convince gcc to accept it via `std::function<int()> b = static_cast<decltype(&g<int>)>(g<int>);`, which is really weird and another good hint that it is a gcc bug

Comment: @idclev463035818 True, that's just an alternative spelling of the same thing. gcc bug it is :)

Comment: @cigien: Here's something *really* bizarre. GCC [works](https://godbolt.org/z/vLzrBH) if you explicitly take `g<int>` and convert it to an `int(*)()` first. What's so bizarre about it is that you don't have to pass the *result* of that conversion to the `std::function`; copy initialization from `g<int>` will work directly, so long as you *at some point in the past* did the cast.

Comment: Could it be implicit conversion into a `std::function<int()>`? It won't be a lambda, it's a `std::function<[the lambda]>` afterwards?

Comment: @NicolBolas gcc also works if I simply make a [call](https://godbolt.org/z/zCm3Pt) like `g<int>();` I think this is related to the `unresolved overloaded function type` part of the error message. So long as the function can be resolved at *some point* I can assign it to a `std::function`, but not otherwise. Maybe this is getting somewhere.

Comment: also a `using funcType = decltype(g<int>);` that you dont use otherwise does the trick: https://godbolt.org/z/X2vV7N

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, I think gcc is fine, so long as it can resolve the function at some point. But why can't if resolve it just for `std::function<int()> b = g<int>;` like clang does? Or is clang doing something it's not supposed to?

Comment: the error message makes no sense its the one you would get when you try to take the adress of eg `void foo(); void foo(int);`, ie when there are more overloads and it cannot be resolved what overload you pick, but there is only one overload of `g`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't really know gcc's diagnostic language in detail, I just assumed it was because `g` is a template.

Comment: I would guess it's because the return type (for both compilers) isn't known until the body of the function is instantiated. This is different from explicitly putting `T` there, because at least then it comes given in the declaration. GCC is probably putting some placeholder there (and it would have to be the same placeholder it probably uses to deal with overloading). Said placeholder should never actually be "visible", because the actual type should be deduced from the `return`, but for whatever reason that doesn't happen (but will if you "encourage" it).

Comment: this is where you get the error (from both): https://godbolt.org/z/wZm__G

Comment: it works if you instantiate `g<int>` somewhere else: https://godbolt.org/z/gT2LL3 so this clearly looks like a bug to me.

Comment: actually all we found out again is already covered in the bug report linked in the first comment. Its just too exciting to experiment with a weird compiler bug ;)

Comment: It's fixed in gcc (trunk) now: https://godbolt.org/z/W4jWMo

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, sweet, thanks. What should I do with this question now?

Comment: @cigien Cheers! I'd leave it open. Someone may fill in the language-lawyer bits at some point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `f()` and `g()` are similar functions, having the same result type.

It was just a bug in GCC, which is fixed in GCC 10.3. Clang and MSVC also accept the program, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qPvar6vTh

So the program is well formed.