# std::bind with variadic template member function and universal references

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, bind, variadic-templates

Here i have small piece of code and it compiles and works just fine
(at least with my GCC 7.3.0 and Ubuntu 18.04):

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void func(int a, const std::string& b, const std::string& c)
{
  std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
}

class Test
{
public:
  template <typename ... ARGS>
  bool func_to_bind(ARGS&& ... args) const {
    func(args...);
    return true;
  }

  template <typename ... ARGS>
  void binding_func(ARGS&& ... args) const 
  {
    auto func_obj = std::bind(&Test::func_to_bind<int&, ARGS&...>, this, 42, args...);
    func_obj();
  }
};


int main()
{
  Test obj;
  obj.binding_func(std::string("one"), std::string("two"));
}
```

The part that i don't understand is this line:

```
std::bind(&Test::func_to_bind<int&, ARGS&...>, this, 42, args...);
```

Why does compiler require to use references as template type parameters?
If i remove reference from int like this:

```
std::bind(&Test::func_to_bind<int, ARGS&...>, this, 42, args...);
```

It won't compile. Also if i change func_to_bind signature to this:

```
bool func_to_bind(ARGS& ... args) const
```

It will compile just fine even with missing reference.
Could anyone explain what's exactly going on here?
I also did some search and found this question: 
[How to combine std::bind(), variadic templates, and perfect forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380820/how-to-combine-stdbind-variadic-templates-and-perfect-forwarding)

But i don't completely understand the answer.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to use `std::bind`.  Lambdas generally make the code easier to write and allow you to avoid having to specify template parameters as it can use overload resolution and template argument deduction for you. `func_obj` can be rewritten as `func_obj = [this](auto&&.. args){ return func_to_bind(42, args...); };`

Comment: It's all good but all I can use is C++ 11 which doesn't have generic parameters for lambdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the template argument as `int` explicitly, then the parameter type of `func_to_bind` would become `int&&`, i.e. an rvalue-reference type. Note that the stored arguments are passed to the invokable object as **lvalue**s by [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> Otherwise, the ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument:

The lvalue can't be bound to the rvalue-referece parameter then invocation fails.

If you specify the template argument as `int&` explicitly, then the parameter type of `func_to_bind` becomes `int&`, i.e. an lvalue-reference type; lvalue could be bound to lvalue-reference then it works fine.

And if you change the parameter type of `func_to_bind` to `ARGS&`, it'll be always an lvalue-reference, for the same reason above it'll work fine.