# c++ how to combine std::bind and variadic tuples?

Tags: c++, templates, bind, variadic-functions

related post: [How to combine std::bind(), variadic templates, and perfect forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380820/how-to-combine-stdbind-variadic-templates-and-perfect-forwarding)

Is there a way to bind a function with variadic tuples ? Here incorrect code indicating the intent:

```
// t is an instance of T
auto f = std::bind(&T::iterate,t,???);
// args is an instance of std::tuple<Args...> args;
std::apply(f,args);
```

(note: I am unsure "variadic tuple" to be the right terminology. Looking forward editing the post with your correction)

Comment: Also, don't use `std::bind`, use lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `bind`, use a lambda instead:

```
auto f = [&t](auto... args){ t.iterate(args...); };
std::apply(f, args);
```

If you want perfect forwarding, that would look like:

```
auto f = [&t](auto&&... args){ t.iterate(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
std::apply(f, args);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since C++20 you can use [std::bind_front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front):

```
template<class T>
void print (T val) {
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

struct T {
    template<class ... Args>
    void iterate(Args... args) {
        int temp[] = { (print(args),0)... };
    }
};

// all happens here
template<class ... Args>
void foo(const tuple<Args...>& args) {
    T t;
    auto f = std::bind_front(&T::iterate<Args...>,&t);
    std::apply(f,args);
}

// the call 
int i = 1;
foo(std::make_tuple(i,i+1,"bind is cool"));
```

If you want to use old [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), you can provide your own placeholders to be generated from pack:

```
template<int N>
struct MyPlaceholder {};

namespace std {
    template<int N>
    struct is_placeholder<MyPlaceholder<N>> : public integral_constant<int, N> {};
}

template<class ... Args, size_t ... Indices>
void foo2helper(const tuple<Args...>& args, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    T t;
    auto f = std::bind(&T::iterate<Args...>,&t, (MyPlaceholder<Indices+1>{})...);
    std::apply(f,args);
}

template<class ... Args>
void foo2(const tuple<Args...>& args) {
    foo2helper(args, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
// the call
foo2(std::make_tuple(2.34,"only bind"));
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ctMpP6)